# Two columns next to each other from two queries in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

How do I get two columns `goed` and `slecht` side by side with the two following queries. They do work independently of each other.

1:

```sql
select count (*) as goed
from movie_info_idx mii 
join title t 
on mii.movie_id = t.id 
join info_type it 
on it.id = mii.info_type_id
join kind_type kt
on kt.id = t.kind_id 
where kt.id = '1'
and it.id = '101'
and mii.info > '7,5'
```

2:

```sql
select count (*) as slecht
from movie_info_idx mii 
join title t 
on mii.movie_id = t.id 
join info_type it 
on it.id = mii.info_type_id
join kind_type kt
on kt.id = t.kind_id 
where kt.id = '1'
and it.id = '101'
and mii.info <= '7,5'
```

But how do I merge both queries so I get two columns `goed` and `slecht` next to each other?

Comment: You could use conditional aggregation. (or even a subquery)

Comment: This microsoft sql example may help you https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/63506/merge-two-select-queries-with-different-where-clauses

Answer (score 0):

Conditional aggregation is likely what you're looking for. Here is an example:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE mii.info > '7,5')  AS goed
     , COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE mii.info <= '7,5') AS slecht
  FROM movie_info_idx mii
  JOIN title t      ON mii.movie_id = t.id
  JOIN info_type it ON mii.info_type_id = it.id
  JOIN kind_type kt ON t.kind_id = kt.id
 WHERE kt.id = '1'
   AND it.id = '101'
;
```

Comment: Thanks J Spratt! Unfortunately that doesn't work, but I'll look into 'Conditional aggregation' if this can solve it.

Comment: Yes! Now I have it. Thank you so much for your help J Spratt. You've made my day. :-)

Comment: Glad I could help. Enjoy!